# Sorting string in C

Tags: c, string, qsort

Well, i'm trying to sort strings alphabetically from file in C, and my program doesn't work. I think mistake in memory allocation for dynamic array, but i can't find it.

```
        #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define buflen 42
int comp(const void * a, const void * b) {
    const char *arraya = *(const char**)a;
    const char *arrayb = *(const char**)b;

    return strcmp(arraya, arrayb);
}
char* getarray(FILE *input)
{
    char buffer[buflen];
    char* result = NULL;
    size_t chargot = 0;
    size_t fact = 0;
    size_t wasinarray = 0;
    while (fgets(buffer, buflen, input))
    {
        chargot = strlen(buffer);
        fact += chargot;
        if (fact >= wasinarray)
        {
            wasinarray += buflen;
            result = realloc(result, wasinarray);
            strcat(result, buffer);
        }
        if (buffer[chargot - 1] == '\n')
            break;
    }
    if (ferror(stdin))
    {
        if (result)
            free(result);
        return NULL;
    }
    return result;
}


int main() {
    char **strarray = NULL;
    int i = 1, strcount = 0;
    char* strline;
    FILE *input, *output; 
    input = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    output = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    strarray = (char**)malloc(i * sizeof(char*));
    while (strline = getarray(input) != NULL)
    {
        strarray[strcount] = strline;
        strarray = (char**)realloc(strarray, (i + 1) * sizeof(char*));
        strcount++;
        i++;
    }
    qsort(strarray, strcount, sizeof(char**), comp);
    for (i = 0; i < strcount; i++)
    {
        fprintf(output, "%s", strarray[i]);
        free(strarray[i]);
    }

    free(strarray);
    free(strline);
    close(output);
    close(input);
    return 0;
}
```

Input and output must be like this

Input:

```
 dfsdfds
 asfsdfds
 badgfdgfd
 csdfdsgfd
```

Output:

```
 asfsdfds 
 badgfdgfd
 csdfdsgfd
 dfsdfds
```

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding, separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line

Comment: when calling any of the heap memory allocation functions: (calloc, malloc, realloc) 1) do not cast the returned value.  Its' type is `void*` so can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when using `#define` to name a integer value, always wrap the integer value in parens to avoid any 'text replacement' errors

Comment: this line: `if (ferror(stdin))` in function: `getarray()` has absolutely nothing to do with the file being read from.  Perhaps you meant: `if (ferror(input))`.

Comment: The function: `free()` can be passed a NULL pointer and `free()` will properly handle it.  so these two lines: `if (result)
            free(result);` can be reduced to: `free(result);`

Comment: the `while()` loop in the function: `getarray()` can be reduced to a single call to `getline()`

Comment: this line: `while (strline = getarray(input) != NULL)` can/will be mis-interpreted by the compiler.  Suggest using parens to force proper evaluation order I.E. `while ( (strline = getarray(input)) != NULL)`

Comment: in the function: `comp()`  the parameters are NOT `const char **` because individual entries being passed are addresses of individual rows.  Instead of lines like: `const char *arraya = *(const char**)a;`  use lines like: `const char *arraya = a;

Comment: when a file is opened with `fopen()` it cannot be closed with `close()`  rather use `fclose()`

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )

Comment: @user3629249 thank you very much) but i dont understand how i can reduce  the while() in getarray() to getline()

Comment: syntax for `getline()` : `ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);`   so in the current scenario:  `chargot = getline( &result, &fact, input );  if( -1 == chargot ) return NULL; else return result;`

Comment: `strcat(result, buffer);` : `result` is uninitialized at first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fix like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define buflen 42

int comp(const void * a, const void * b) {
    return strcmp(*(const char**)a, *(const char**)b);
}

char* getarray(FILE *input){
    char buffer[buflen];
    char* result = NULL;
    size_t chargot = 0;
    size_t fact = 0;

    while (fgets(buffer, buflen, input)){
        chargot = strlen(buffer);
        result = realloc(result, fact + chargot + 1);
        memcpy(result + fact, buffer, chargot + 1);
        fact += chargot;
        if (buffer[chargot - 1] == '\n')
            return result;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(void){
    char **strarray = NULL;
    int i = 0, strcount = 0;
    char* strline;
    FILE *input, *output;

    input = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    output = fopen("output.txt", "w");

    while ((strline = getarray(input)) != NULL){
        strarray = realloc(strarray, (i + 1) * sizeof(char*));
        strarray[i++] = strline;
    }

    qsort(strarray, (strcount=i), sizeof(char*), comp);
    for (i = 0; i < strcount; i++){
        fprintf(output, "%s", strarray[i]);//!!Input line includes always newline
        free(strarray[i]);
    }

    free(strarray);
    fclose(output);
    fclose(input);
    return 0;
}
```